# HTML X-UA-Compatible tag not working in IE 9

Tags: html, grails, internet-explorer-9, knockout.js

I am getting the error: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=7') ignored because document mode is already finalized.

I have read that the fix for this is that the meta tag is not declared high enough in the head tag, however I have tried moving this meta tag to be the very first line of the head tag and that does not fix the error.

I am working in a Grails .gsp file and the file also uses knockout js.

Here is the relevant code:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html lang="en" class="no-js ie6"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html lang="en" class="no-js ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html lang="en" class="no-js"><!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>myInfinitec Membership Management</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ucpmanagementportal/static/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <meta name="layout" content="main"/>




        <script src="/ucpmanagementportal/static/plugins/jquery-1.7.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<link href="/ucpmanagementportal/static/bundle-bundle_coreCSS_head.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" />



    </head>
```

Edit:  In the IE developer window there are "Text- empty text node" lines being generated between every line. Perhaps this counts as having something before the X-UA-Compatible meta tag.  I read that the fix is to add display: block and zoom: 1 to the affected elements but this does not work.  Here is an example of what I am describing:

```
<head>
Text - Empty Text Node
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
Text - Empty Text Node
<meta style="display: block; zoom: 1;" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
Text - Empty Text Node
```

Comment: Your x-ua-compatible attribute is set to edge?

Comment: What should it be set to instead?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want IE 7 compatability, then it would be IE=7,chrome=1. Possibly there is another x-ua-compatible  introduced elsewhere?

Comment: Hmm, maybe I do want IE=7 however I don't think that is the fix to this problem.  The problem is that the meta tag is being skipped, regardless of the IE value.  I can confirm that there are no other X-UA-Compatible lines in the file.

Comment: `style` to a meta?  first time I see that

Comment: When they said 'to the affected elements' I think they meant actual page elements, not the meta tag.  This is what meta tag should look like... `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >`  (for example) read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The style was added to try to fix the Text - empty text node issue.  With or without the style, and with or without setting IE=EmulateIE7 instead of IE=edge, the x-ua-compatible meta tag is still skipped with the error: X-UA-Compatible META tag ('IE=7') ignored because document mode is already finalized.  I think this is an indicator that the error must not be related to the value of the meta tag, but rather that some tag before it is causing the document to be finalized.

Comment: maybe the server is already sending an http-equiv?  I recommend you use Firefox, get the Firebug add-on, and when you see your page check the 'Net' tab and look at the 'Headers', maybe there's already something there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay well I solved my problem, though my problem turned out to have nothing to do with the error I was describing.  I was experiencing errors due to IE's caching of ajax calls and was able to fix the issue by adding jQuery.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }).

Answer (score 0):

This did not ever work for me. The fix I found is to add the X-UA-Compatible value to a before Interceptor of each controller and that seemed to make it work everytime. For example, in each controller I had

```
def beforeInterceptor = [action : this.&setBrowserCompat]

private setBrowserCompat(){
response.addHeader("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge")
}
```

This seemed to always work. Hope this is helpful